# Mental Model for how web browser works

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to form a good mental model of how the various components of a web browser work together. So far, what I have is that the browser is composed of a layout engine and the browser chrome. The part I am struggling with is how javascript interacts with the DOM and the browser. Does the layout engine (WebKit, etc.) run the javascript interpreter? Is the DOM a tree data structure created by the engine to which javascript has access? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely not programming, but you can have a look at [this good article (How Browsers Work: Behind the Scenes of Modern Web Browsers <sup>HTML5 Rocks</sup>)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)